How to always generate yaml with the same element order using io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2?
I need to generate the yaml file for my application, but I need it to be the same every time I generate it in order to compare it the current generated yaml with the current state of my API.
But I'm having trouble making this comparison deterministic.
Is there any way I can make swagger to:

Generate the yaml file with the same element order?
Generate the same yaml file if no changes to the endpoint codes are made?

I know springdoc has some configurations to do that, but my project does not use spring.
Notes

I'm using io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2:2.0.1.


Alternative solution - sort the OpenAPI YAML files before comparing them. For example, you can use yq to sort YAML files.
# *nix/macOS

cat old.yaml | yq -P 'sort_keys(..)' > old-sorted.yaml
cat new.yaml | yq -P 'sort_keys(..)' > new-sorted.yaml

diff old-sorted.yaml new-sorted.yaml

